# Проблема с использованием параметра OFFSET в sql-запросе

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте!

Пытаюсь реализовать постраничную навигацию. Проблема встала в выдаче следующей ошибки:

> "ERROR: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error
> or access violation: 1064 You have an
> error in your SQL syntax; check the
> manual that corresponds to your MySQL
> server version for the right syntax to
> use near ''5',5' at line 1"

Сам запрос, в котором сервер видит ошибку:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM male_articles ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT :offset,:limit');
$stmt->bindValue(':limit', $count, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindValue(':offset', $start, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
$pages = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Пробовал и так, как выше, и так:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM male_articles ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset');
$stmt->bindValue(':limit', $count, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindValue(':offset', $start, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
$pages = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Судя по выводу цифр в ошибке, переменные туда попадают. Не могу понять, чем не нравится такой запрос серверу...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы строку отправляете, а нужно число. Приведите тип лимита и офсета.

```
(int) $count
(int) $start
```

Comment: Вы правы, спасибо огромное! Оказывается, PDO::PARAM_INT недостаточно...